# How can I erase a line from a ini file using php?

Tags: php, line, erase

Does someone know how can I find a line in a ini file and erase using php?

fopen etc..?

Comment: do you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
$content = '';
// iterate over each line of the ini file
foreach(file('your.ini') as $line) {
     // if the line doesn't start with YOURKEY ...
     if(!preg_match('~^YOURKEY~', $str)) {
         // add it to output
         $content .= $line;
     }
}
file_put_contents('your.ini', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has `parse_ini_file` which is great for read but not something similar for writes.  Have a look at http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite?  This should make your task simple.